# Conditional font color for text within a cell in a gt table

Tags: r, tidyverse, gt

I am trying to find out if there is a way to color specific text within a cell with the Gt package in R. I don't have a reproducible example since I haven't found any tutorials or examples of how to do this.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

type <- c("A", "B")
track <- c("G-P-L-H-H", "G-H-P-L-G")

table <- tibble(type, track) %>% gt()
```

For the table above, on the track column I'd like the font color of G = red, H = blue, L = green and P = yellow. is there a way to achieve this? This is a small representation of the real table I am working with, which will have many more rows with random combination of letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this achieve what you need? I replace, for example, "G" with G inside an `html` tag with style corresponding to the needed color.

[image]

```
table <- tibble(type, track) %>%
  mutate(
    track = track %>%
      str_replace_all("G", '<a style="color:red">G</a>') %>%
      str_replace_all("H", '<a style="color:blue">H</a>') %>%
      str_replace_all("L", '<a style="color:green">L</a>') %>%
      str_replace_all("P", '<a style="color:yellow">P</a>')
    ) %>%
  gt() %>%
  fmt_markdown(columns = "track")
```

Comment: I ended up implementing this solution. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The `gt` package has a function `text_transform()` for this purpose:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gt)

type <- c("A", "B")
track <- c("G-P-L-H-H", "G-H-P-L-G")

tibble(type, track) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  text_transform(locations = cells_body(vars(track)), 
                 fn = function(x) {
                   x <- gsub("G", "<span style=\"color: red;\">G</span>", x)
                   x <- gsub("H", "<span style=\"color: blue;\">H</span>", x)
                   x <- gsub("L", "<span style=\"color: green;\">L</span>", x)
                   x <- gsub("P", "<span style=\"color: yellow;\">P</span>", x)
                 })
```

[image]

Comment: I went for another solution but this was also a valid one. Thank you.